# [teams]How to update messaging endpoint via API or SDK?

Tags: api, botframework

I am working on a chatbot in NodeJs and we are using Ngrok to establish a tunnel, the problem we have for teams is that every time we relaunch Ngrok we get a diferent url so i have to manually change the messaging endpoint on the botframework website(under settings)
   Is there a way to do this via the api? or maybe the SDK?
   This was not an issue for other chat platforms but for Teams i cannot find this feature.

Claudiu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike some other chat/bot platforms, Bot Framework (and therefore Teams) works by having the chat service initiate the connection to the bot instead of the other way around. That's why every bot requires an https: endpoint.

Ngrok is one way to do it without running the bot in the cloud, but as you note those temporary URLs only last 7 hours. You can purchase the premium version of Ngrok which lets you have static subdomains - for example at our Build conference I used https://build2018.ngrok.io.

One of our developers also created [Tunnel Relay](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-tunnelrelay) which you can download. The utility itself is free but you have to have an Azure subscription and use Azure Service Bus - which at the basic tier is $0.05 per million transactions. All the details, including a download link, are on the GitHub page linked above.

There is no public API for changing your bot's messaging endpoint. (If there were, it would be a great way to steal the traffic from other bots.)

Comment: Thanks Bill, i will go for a paid Ngrok subscription :-)